# Isn't it that function expression should be declared before calling the function? Then why does this code work?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
"use strict";


let numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.drum').length;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

        let buttonId = this.id;
        makeSound(buttonId);
    });
}

// for detecting keyboard key press
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    makeSound(event.key);
})

let makeSound = function (key) {

    switch (key) {
        case "a":
            CssKeyPress('a');
            var audio = new Audio('./sounds/tom1.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;
} 

let CssKeyPress = function (id) {
    let getId = document.getElementById(id);
    getId.classList.add('keypress');
    setTimeout(function () {
            getId.classList.remove('keypress');
        },
        100);
}
```

I don't know why this is working? Can somebody explain it to me? So, I thought with function expressions you cannot call it before the function is declared. But, I have called the `CssKeyPress()` function and `makeSound()` function before they get declared why does it work?

Comment: Because `makeSound` is not called until after `CssKeyPress` gets assigned to, nor is the `keypress` event fired before `makeSound` gets assigned to

Comment: in addition, if you declared your functions in the mormal way - as `function makeSound(key) {...}` rather than `let makeSound = function(key) {...}`, then hoisting would (effectively) move them to the top of their scope anyway. [The way you have it now, it's nothing to do with hoisting, but I thought I'd mention this because it does come up in similar cases. @CertainPerformance has already explained why this works in your case.]